# ¿Como imprimir en modo Impresora Genérica en impresoras ticketeras desde Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, impresión

Buen día.

Estoy realizando una aplicación (sistema de ventas) de escritorio en Windows forms de Visual Studio. Y deseo imprimir en las impresoras térmicas (y similares como las ticketeras matriciales) de papel continuo. Hay aplicaciones hechas en delphi que solo necesitan indicar el nombre de la impresora en mención e imprimir en ella a cuya configuración de la impresora es con un driver texto genérico. Ademas estas impresoras cortan el papel.

Necesito un código en C# o VB que imprima una bloque de texto (varias lineas con imagen posible, código de barras posible u otros elementos-así como las boletas de supermercado o similar-), además que la impresora corte automáticamente el papel. (Ej. star sp500).

Gracias por su ayuda.

P.D. indicarle el ancho de papel.

Answer (score 3):

Buenas,

Para hacer todo esto primero debes configurar bien los drivers de la impresora en el mismo ordenador, indicando el tamaño de la hoja que se va a imprimir y todas las preferencias sobre el método de impresión.

Éste código es el que hay que tener en el botón de print:

```
// Declaramos un PrintDocument
PrintDocument pd = new PrintDocument(); 
// Indicamos la impresora con la que se va a imprimir el pd
pd.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = "Nombre_Impresora";
// Añadimos la función pd_PrintPage al evento Print
pd.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler(pd_PrintPage);
// Imprimimos el documento.
pd.Print();
```

Función pd_PrintPage():

```
 private void pd_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs ev) 
 {
     // Cambiamos la fuente a lo que nosotros queramos
     // Aquí puedes poner la fuente de código de barras también, antes debe estar instalada en el equipo
     printFont = new Font("Arial", 10);

     // Obtenemos la configuración de la impresora para saber tamaño de papel, método de impresión, etc..
     PrinterSettings Prt = new PrinterSettings();
     Prt.PrinterName = "Nombre_Impresora";
     PSize = Prt.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize;
     // ...
 }
```

A partir de aquí todo lo demás son cálculos jugando siempre con el PrintPageEventArgs.

Ejemplo:

```
// Calcular las líneas por página
linPerPag = ev.MarginBounds.Height / printFont.GetHeight(ev.Graphics) ;

// Imprimir un texto
ev.Graphics.DrawString("Texto", printFont, Brushes.Black, xPos, yPos, new StringFormat());

// Imprimir imagen de un PictureBox
ev.Graphics.DrawImage(PictureBox1.Image, ev.MarginBounds.Left, ev.MarginBounds.Top)
```

Espero que te sirva de ayuda

Comment: Gracias, pero no veo donde esta el comando de corte de papel.

Comment: Buenas, hice una aplicación que lo único que hacia era imprimir dependiendo de unas configuraciones puestas por el usuario, pero no eran impresoras cortadoras. Deberías mirar los manuales de las impresoras para las que estas realizando el programa y ver que comando usan para cortar el papel, normalmente funciona enviando una cadena de bytes al dispositivo.